# Trying to use an inclusive range with SecureRandom.random_number ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, random, range

I'm using `securerandom` and the problem is that it is including the digit `"0"`, as in `0..56`, and `0..46` instead of `1..56`, and `1..46` (lottery tickets do not include the 0 digit). The 0 can be seen in the 2nd mega number output below. I thought I figured out a way to exclude the `0`s below with (`char1`, `char2`), but I failed.

When I use `rand(1..56)` with an inclusive range it works just fine (but several posts suggest to stay away from `rand()`). However when I attempt to use an inclusive range with `char1` and `char2` below on `securerandom` it doesn't work.

```
Error:
[nil@nil lottery]$ ./mega_millions.rb 
/dev/null/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb:216:in `<': comparison of Fixnum with Array failed (ArgumentError)
        from /dev/null/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb:216:in `random_number'
        from ./mega_millions.rb:42:in `<main>'
```

I would appreciate any feedback and a shove in the right direction.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rainbow.rb'
require 'securerandom'

quick_pick = 56
char1  = ('1'..'56').to_a 

mega_num = 46
char2  = ('1'..'46').to_a 

first  = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick)
second = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick)
third  = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick)
fourth = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick)
fifth  = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick)
mega   = SecureRandom.random_number(mega_num)

puts "#{first}, #{second}, #{third}, #{fourth}, #{fifth}, #{mega}"


[nil@nil lottery]$ ./mega_millions.rb 
34, 38, 17, 24, 55, 14
[nil@nil lottery]$ ./mega_millions.rb 
30, 26, 7, 4, 32, 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation to [SecureRandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-random_number) states:

> If a positive integer is given as n, ::random_number returns an integer: 0 <= ::random_number < n.

Therefore, this should do the trick:

```
first  = SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick) + 1
# And so forth...
```

That will result in a random number in the range `1..quickpick`, inclusive.

Without adding the `1`, you end up in the range `0..(quickpick-1)`, inclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Def helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You could simply add 1 to your random number, like so:

```
quick_pick = 55 # 56 - 1 to account for the offset in your range of numbers
SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick) + 1
```

By the way, more idiomatically, you can run that multiple times like so:

```
numbers = 6.times.collect { SecureRandom.random_number(quick_pick) + 1 }
```

And then print it with

```
puts numbers.join(', ')
```

Comment: This is also a great response. I tried to upvote it but the sys mentioned I could not do it until I have 15 reputation points (which is silly imo). Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am def keeping the one liner handy as well.

Answer (score 1):

For a true one-liner:

```
puts 6.times.collect{ SecureRandom.random_number(55) + 1 }.join(', ')
```

unless you need to retain the numbers for some reason after printing them.

Revising slightly to generate mega millions:

```
puts 5.times.collect{SecureRandom.random_number(55) + 1}.push(SecureRandom.random_number(45) + 1).join(', ')
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I would upvote if I could. The reason I chose not to stick with a true one-liner is because mega millions has five numbers ranging from 1..56, and a sixth mega number ranging from 1..46. I will eventually see if I could make a one liner with the above specs.

Comment: Thanks for the mega millions revision. You didn't have to do it, lol, as I wanted to struggle a bit ;) but thanks for the awesome support. I love this community!

Comment: You're welcome.  Your feedback motivated me to try to get it right.